# Linux/open-source program to open (OrCAD) schematics for BeagleBone?

Tags: schematics, beagleboard, orcad

I'm trying to open [BeagleBone](http://beagleboard.org)'s schematics for an OrCAD file in Linux, but *[EAGLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAGLE_%28program%29)* seems unable to do the job. What are some options?

Original Orcad ZIP file: http://beagleboard.org/static/beaglebone/a3/Docs/Hardware/BONE_SCH.zip

Which extracts to:

```
BEAGLEBONE_REV A3A.DSN
```

Comment: I tried opening it with Pulsonix, which can deal with many schematic and PCB file formats, but was unsuccessful. It's been saved as a binary file, it needs to be an ASCII file.

Comment: Do you want to be able to modify those schematics? If not, just open the [PDF schematics](http://beagleboard.org/static/beaglebone/a3/Docs/Hardware/BONE_SCH.pdf)

Comment: yes looking for an editor function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no open source program to edit OrCAD files. That is such a small niche and depends on a proprietary file format that I wouldn't expect one to ever exist.

Answer (score 1):

EEVblog suggested in 2012 that there were conversion tools in upverter, and DSN was on the list for future development.

http://www.eevblog.com/forum/open-source-kicad-geda/schematic-converter-project/

Answer (score 0):

You can install Free VMware Player, thus create a virtual machine with Windows XP or any other version of Windows.

Comment: That won't help, the problem is the binary file format.

Comment: Thanks, I know this can work, and it still won't solve my problem. I am actually running windows host with a vm linux guest.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing ORCAD on Linux using Wine.
Other available options are mentioned in this [link](http://www.cnx-software.com/2012/05/14/schematics-capture-and-pcb-layout-in-linux-with-kicad/) i.e.

1. Kicad
2. gEDA
3. Cadsoft Eagle